# Criar uma coluna Boolean em Banco Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, pl-sql, booleano

Em um banco oracle tenho de criar um coluna com o tipo Boolean

> ALTER TABLE dbamv.prepad ADD editavel BOOLEAN default FALSE;

Porém o banco exibi uma mensagem de erro:

> ORA-00902: tipo de dados inválido ALTER TABLE dbamv.pre_pad ADD
>   editavel BOOLEAN default FALSE

Comment: é o mesmo problema seu acredito https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19518415/boolean-giving-invalid-datatype-oracle

Comment: Oracle não suporta este Type , crie como NUMBER(1) e inclua uma constraint para 0 ou 1   https://imasters.com.br/banco-de-dados/implementando-campos-booleanos